# How to open Google PDF Viewer app?

Tags: app-icons

I can't find Google PDF Viewer app icon even though I have installed it from Google Play Store. How can I open it?

Also, I'm unable to close display green light on top of display screen.

Comment: It seems you have 2 questions that are unrelated. For the second question regarding "close display green light on top of display screen", could you post that as a new question and provide the screenshot? As of current writing, it's unclear what you meant by that.

Answer (score 2):

Google PDF Viewer doesn't have app icon.

However, when you're trying to open a PDF file from other apps (e.g. Download, or any file manager like ES File Explorer), it will be listed as one of possible app inside App Chooser dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Google PDF Viewer is a triggered app. The only way to open it is using automation app or use Nova launcher, add a shortcut to activity on home to launch main activity of the Google PDF Viewer